# Elegant way to get 'highest level' from SQL

Tags: sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a table that maintains a relationship between entities and some arbitrarily defined 'level'.
I've abstracted this out to be like a parent-child relationship.
Note - I have no power over the schema of the table.

Table:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE Roles (
    Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Role VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);

-- data
INSERT INTO Roles
    (Name, Role)
VALUES
('John Smith','GrandParent'),
('John Smith','Parent'),
('John Smith','Child'),
('John Smith','Grandchild'),
('Aaron Chow','Parent'),
('Aaron Chow','Child'),
('Aaron Chow','Grandchild'),
('Bob Johnson','GrandParent'),
('Bob Johnson','Parent'),
('Bob Johnson','Child'),
('Glenda Michaels','Parent'),
('Glenda Michaels','Child'),
('Glenda Michaels','Grandchild'),
('Glenda Michaels','Greatgrandchild'),
('Charlie Doe','Child');
```

Now, I want to be able to query a particular name, and get the 'highest level' associated with that name based on some mapping I identify. In this case:
Grandparent is the 'highest'
Then Parent
Then Child
Then Grandchild
And Greatgrandchild is the 'lowest' level

I have a working SQL that allows me to do this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        (
            MIN(
                CASE
                    Role
                    WHEN 'GrandParent' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Parent' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Child' THEN 3
                    WHEN 'Grandchild' THEN 4
                    WHEN 'Greatgrandchild' THEN 5
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            )
        )
        WHEN 1 THEN 'GrandParent'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Parent'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Child'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Grandchild'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Greatgrandchild'
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    Roles
WHERE
    name = 'Aaron Chow'
```

Note - expected result is 'Parent'

Where I build that hash-map in the SQL, then I get the min value, and then map that value back to the 'level'.

Now this SQL is a bit messy and would be prone to user error (e.g. if the values are mapped differentially in the two case statements).

Is there a more elegant or robust way to accomplish this?

EDIT: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f39b2/5/0

Comment: Please provide expected result

Comment: You could create a second table to hold the mapping `role | level`. This way everyone that uses this table doesn't have to build this case statement out every time.

Comment: I would argue too that this is not a `roles` table. Instead it's a `user_roles` table. Your `roles` table would be more like the one I described. Maybe even `role_id, role_name, role_level`. And then your existing table would hold the `role_id` instead of the `role_name` like it does today. You can establish foreign key relationship here for data integrity and it will all scale nicely.

Comment: I think this would be an ideal solution, but I don't have any way of creating an intermediate table or impacting any schemas in any way. Any of my logic has to be done in the SQL statement...

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above.

I think a new table to hold your `roles` attributes would be beneficial. You could hold the `role_name` and it's `level` here. You can then use `role_id` to join the two tables.

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca437/4)

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE User_Roles (
    Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Role_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);

-- data
INSERT INTO User_Roles
    (Name, Role_id)
VALUES
('John Smith',1),
('John Smith',2),
('John Smith',3),
('John Smith',4),
('Aaron Chow',2),
('Aaron Chow',3),
('Aaron Chow',4),
('Bob Johnson',1),
('Bob Johnson',2),
('Bob Johnson',3),
('Glenda Michaels',2),
('Glenda Michaels',3),
('Glenda Michaels',4),
('Glenda Michaels',5),
('Charlie Doe',3)
;

CREATE TABLE roles (role_id INT, role_name VARCHAR(25), role_level int);

INSERT INTO roles 
VALUES (1, 'GrandParent', 1),
(2, 'Parent', 2),
(3, 'Child', 3),
(4, 'Grandchild', 4),
(5, 'GreatGrandChild', 5);


SELECT role_name 
FROM roles
WHERE role_id =
  (
    SELECT min(role_level) 
    FROM user_roles 
      INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.role_id
    WHERE name = 'Aaron Chow'
   );
```

What's nice here is that if you wanted to change your role levelling at some point in the future (say you decide that Parent should outlevel Grandparent, then you can just:

```
UPDATE roles SET role_level = 1 WHERE role_id = 2;
UPDATE roles SET role_level = 2 WHERE role_id = 1;
```

And all of your results will fall in line without having to monkey with your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting it by role in the order of level and then use `LIMIT 1` to return the top level.

```
SELECT role
FROM
roles
WHERE name = 'Aaron Chow'
ORDER BY
               CASE
                    Role
                    WHEN 'GrandParent' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Parent' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Child' THEN 3
                    WHEN 'Grandchild' THEN 4
                    WHEN 'Greatgrandchild' THEN 5
                    ELSE 6
                END
LIMIT 1;
```

Could use `WITH` (cte) to build a temp result set to associate each role with the corresponding level.  The following is tested in mySQL 8.0:

```
WITH Role_Level as
( SELECT 'GrandParent' as Role,
          1 as Level 
  UNION
  SELECT 'Parent', 2 
  UNION
  SELECT 'Child', 3
  UNION
  SELECT 'Grandchild', 4
  UNION
  SELECT 'Greatgrandchild', 5 )
SELECT r.Role
FROM
Roles r
JOIN
Role_Level l
ON r.Role = l.Role
WHERE r.Name = 'Aaron Chow'
ORDER BY l.Level
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but it's not the most robust :/

Comment: @SimaPro are you on mysql?  Does your version support cte?

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with CTE, but quickly googling it - if you're talking about 'WITH ' clauses, then yes. Recursive queries - i'm not sure...

Comment: @SimaPro updated the answer to use `WITH` clause to build a temp result set for the roles and their corresponding level.  This is a workaround if you are not able to change the schema.